# When to use IBAction vs. UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift

I have seen **storyboard** buttons combined with IBAction code as well as UITapGestureRecognizers (not speaking here of programtically defined buttons).

I am curious if there is any (not strongly opinionated) reason to prefer one over the other in specific situations.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons have their own tap action events.
All other UI elements have no.

E.g., if you want to handle label tap event you have to use gesture recognizers.

Comment: So would you say it's generally not a good idea to use tap events on buttons, because there is something triggered double or something like that? 
I am just curious why people use tap gesture recognizers in the first place when there are also button specific events.

Comment: It depends on many things. For example, code reuse or project style guide.

Answer (score 1):

UIButtons have actions. you don't need tap gesture for it. You may need tap gesture for UILabel or UIView.